# Receive data from server with JSON and Swift

Tags: json, server, ios9

I'm trying send data from my app to my server, but now i need to receive some data and put into an array.

Here is my code:

```
//declare parameter as a dictionary which contains string as key and value combination

let parameters = ["marchio": newVettura.cognome, "user": newVettura.targa ] as Dictionary<String, String>

    //create the url with NSURL
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://parts.gibiauto.com/ciccio.php") //change the url

    //create the session object
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    //now create the NSMutableRequest object using the url object
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

    let err: NSError?
    //request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: nil, error: &err)
    request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options:[])// pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard data != nil else {
            print("no data found: \(error)")
            return
        }

        // this, on the other hand, can quite easily fail if there's a server error, so you definitely
        // want to wrap this in `do`-`try`-`catch`:

        do {
            if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                let success = json["success"] as? Int                                  // Okay, the `json` is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
                print("Success: \(success)")
            } else {
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)    // No error thrown, but not NSDictionary
                print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
            }
        } catch let parseError {
            print(parseError)                                                          // Log the error thrown by `JSONObjectWithData`
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
    }

    task.resume() }
```

Now, how can i memorize into an array that the server send me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [this part of the SDK](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/). On the other hand, you obviously already know that, because you use it to create the data to pass with the request.

This leaves as another answer:

Add an instance variable to your class to store the result. When the asynchronous block gets executed and you are happy with the result, assign it to the instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
do{
  valuearray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray
  let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Encrypt.self, from: data!)
  print(json as Any)
  } catch let err as NSError { print(err) }
       for anItem in valuearray as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
           let ascii_text = anItem["ascii_text"] as! String
           let random_text = anItem["random_text"] as! String
       }
```